# How do I decide whether to create a new window when i Click on a button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a little window (winReset) that appears on starting the application. Upon pressing done, the Main Window opens.

However, Main Window contains a button that when clicked, opens winReset again. When you click Done on winReset this time, I don't want a new instance of Main Window, unlike the first time. I just want to close winReset.

I'm having trouble with the code behind here.

Here's what I have so far in the code behind of my winReset but it's not working:

```
private void btnClickDone(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Window win = App.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == "main");

        if (win.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            this.Close();
        }

        else
        {
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
            App.Current.MainWindow = main;
            this.Close();
            main.Show();
          }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new MainWindow only if one doesn't exist already. If one does, then just close the current winReset. I'm not sure why I'm struggling with this but I can't seem to figure this out. Any help?

Comment: That is simple to solve. When you recreate `winReset`, set a `bool` variable like `showMain` to `false`. Once this variable is `false`, clicking **done** will close the application.

Comment: How do I reference a variable from another window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check App.Current.MainWindow like this:

```
if (App.Current.MainWindow != null && App.Current.MainWindow.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
{
    this.Close();
}
else
{
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    App.Current.MainWindow = main;
    this.Close();
    main.Show();
}
```

Comment: this way eveytime you create a new instance of mainWindow

Comment: Outside of the if statement, how can I refer to the MainWindow? I can't do a `main = App.Current.MainWindow();`

Comment: You have to cast its type. You can do `var main = App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow` or `var main = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow`... Don't confuse your `MainWindow` class with the `MainWindow` property of the `Application` class, even if they have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You can create main as local object and then check if its null or not..

```
Private MainWindow _main = null;
```

Then in handler --

```
if(_main == null)
    _main = new MainWindow();

App.Current.MainWindow = _main;
this.Close();
_main.Show();
```

Comment: If I create _main in my MainWindow, how can I use it in my winReset window?

Comment: App Current MainWindow will have reference to your MainWindow

Comment: _main = App.Current.MainWindow    where needed

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to be working. To create the first mainWindow, it works. But when I click the button and create a new winReset, upon clicking Done, a new window of Main appears.

Comment: you need to set _main window before you open your popup and keep a reference to it

Answer (score 0):

When you want to follow your approach, this should work for you:

```
Window win = App.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.DependencyObjectType.Name == "MainWindow");
if (win != null)
{
  this.Close();
}
else
{
  MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
  App.Current.MainWindow = main;
  this.Close();
  main.Show();
}
```