# How to refer to current open window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window popping up, and a MainWindow is created if one doesn't exist already:

```
if (App.Current.MainWindow != null && App.Current.MainWindow.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
{
    this.Close();
}
else
{
        //main Window hasn't been created yet so create it!
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        App.Current.MainWindow = main;
        this.Close();
        main.Show();
        wndw = main;
    }
```

How do I refer to the MainWindow so I can use it outside the if statement?

I want to be able to do `main.txbox.Text = ....` etc.

Here's what I've tried:

```
MainWindow main;
if 
{...
}
else
{...
}
main= App.Current.MainWindow;
```

or `MainWindow main = App.Current.MainWindow();`

Neither of these approaches seem to work. I'm sure this is really simple, I just can't figure out the syntax. Help?

Edit: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542339) I asked earlier, but different because here I'm asking about syntax when referencing the currently opened window. The similar question is referring to how to detect which window is opened. They're similar, but I didn't want to go off topic.

Comment: please continue in you the question you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542339/how-do-i-decide-whether-to-create-a-new-window-when-i-click-on-a-button/31542565?noredirect=1#comment51045144_31542565)

Comment: It's very bad idea to write straight to another window controls for example text box. Better do this by the binded property.

Comment: @Muds Posting a new question for a new doubt is perfectly fine. Helps keep the other question clean of off-topics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way

```
 var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
```

Answer (score 0):

In some base class or App.xaml.cs create this:

```
   public static Window ActivatedWindow {get;set;}
```

Then put in your base class deriving Window or all of your Window's Activate Event:

First Option - personal Window Base Class:

```
   public class MetroToolWindowBase
   {
     public MetroToolWindowBase()
     {   
        Activated += new EventHandler(MakeActive); 
     }   
     private void MakeActive(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
    App.ActivatedWindow= this;
     }
   }
```

Second Option- In Activated Event of Windows:

```
 private void XWindow_Activated(object sender,EventArgs e)
  {
  App.ActivatedWindow= this;
  }
```